# No. 2: What's the next in this letter sequence?

Tags: pattern, knowledge

Part of a series of similar puzzles - the answer to one will give you the type of thinking required for the others.

What's the next letter in this series? What's the relationship?

```
G
J
T
J
J
J
A
M
W
J
J
Z
M
F
J
A
A
U
R
J
C
G
B
G
W
T
W
W
W
C
H
F
H
D
J
L
R
G
J
R
G
B
G
B
```

This one might be harder than the last, so I can give a hint sooner if there is enough demand.

Comment: Does/can this sequence continue infinitely?

Comment: Nope - that's a big hint!

Comment: Maybe it should be W-G-B as the last three instead of B-G-B?

Comment: Good thinking - but I went off a few official lists that described it this way. - For those that are reading this - this is a big hint!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next letter is

> D for **D**onald

As the list is the

> Initials of the given names of [US presidents](http://www.ipl.org/div/potus/) from **G**eorge Washington to  **B**arack Obama.

Comment: Wrong answer, but correct reasoning! I'm surprised it was that easy!!

Comment: Thanks, sorry I was in mbl and didn't see the rest. The answer to No. 1 was very helpful. I updated now.  I see about there being something wrong .